# Why do I need to return for this function to work?

Tags: python

```
def hotel_cost(days):
    return 140 * days

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    else:
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost_times_day = days * 40
    if days >= 7:
        cost_times_day = cost_times_day - 50
        print cost_times_day
        return cost_times_day
    elif days >= 3 and days <7:
        cost_times_day = cost_times_day - 20

        **return cost_times_day**    # right here!!!! <--- if I remove this I       #get the error, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and  #'int'

    else:
        print cost_times_day
        return cost_times_day

def trip_cost(city, days, spending_money):
    return rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) +\
    spending_money

print trip_cost("Los Angeles", 5, 600)
```

Answer (score 1):

Becuase, if `rental_car_cost` does not return a value, then in: `trip_cost`, exactly in this line:

```
return rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) +\
    spending_money
```

You are trying to sum a `NoneType` with an `int`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you don't have to return from that line... Further, it's bad practice to return from each one of your if/elif branches, a better approach would be:

```
def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost_times_day = days * 40
    if days >= 7:
        cost_times_day -= 50
        print cost_times_day
    elif days >= 3 and days <7:
        cost_times_day -= 20    
    return cost_times_day  # <-- a single point of return
```

If you have a branch that doesn't return a value, Python, by default will return `None` which will cause failure in the caller function when it tries to add `int` to `None`, hence the error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and  #'int'

Comment: I am confused. If the function got a value greater then 7 how would it know that the value is without returning it in each statement?

Comment: Checkout the code again, it actually *does* return a value, only that it's done only once, at the end of the function ;)

Comment: Ahh I see. Your very helpful. Last question. If it returns after that last line then why wouldn't it only return for the last elif part. For example the first if part cuts off before the function returns it and then the elif part begins and ends with a return.

Comment: Because of the indentation, after it finishes executing the if/elif - the functions end with a return statement

Answer (score 0):

Your error is really here:

```
return rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city)
```

You are trying to add the result of `rental_car_cost(days)` to the other costs, and when you comment out the line you mentioned, there is a case where `rental_car_cost` doesn't return anything (i.e. returns `None`). So it blows up when you try to add `None` to an `int`.

To fix this make sure that every code path (every possible path through your `if` statements, in particular) returns a valid `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`if days >= 3 and days < 7` and you remove the return statement that you have highlighted, the `rental_car_cost()` function will return `None`. When the `trip_cost()` function tries to concatenate `None` and two numbers, it will fail because it is not possible.